# What is the cheapest metro system in the world?

Tags: trains, public-transport, budget, where-on-earth, factoids

When traveling I am trying to avoid using the underground/metro/subway because I want to see the city I am visiting, but sometimes for long distances it is much quicker than any other form of transport.

So which city has the cheapest underground system? I'm looking for the cheapest available single fare price. It is okay if I have to use a pre-paid card as long as I can buy it right in the station.

On contender is Mexico City: [image: Metro Prices in Mexico City in 2008]

Photo credit: [Peter Hahndorf](http://peter.hahndorf.eu)

In 2008 the price for a single ride was 2 pesos or € 0.10 (US$ 0.15), it is now up to 3 pesos, but that is still very cheap.

Comment: Cheapest for you or for the locals?

Comment: Public transport in Tallinn is free to the passengers (but there is no metro, only bus, trams and trolleybus). [Free public transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_public_transport) is a thing now, but mostly in small to medium-sized cities with bus networks but no metro.

Comment: @Relaxed though you have to be registered as a resident of Tallinn (essentially live there) to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [PriceOfTravel.com](http://www.priceoftravel.com/595/public-transportation-prices-in-80-worldwide-cities/):

*all prices converted into US dollars in mid-November, 2010

Price ranges reflect shortest to longest rides in most cities. Tourists are most likely to pay the lowest price.

- Caracas, Venezuela (metro, bus) $0.12 – $0.28
- Cairo, Egypt (metro) $0.17
- Delhi, India (metro) $0.18 – $0.66
- La Paz, Bolivia (bus) $0.19 – $0.50
- Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia (light rail, bus) $0.22 – $0.76
- Marrakech, Morocco (bus) $0.24 – $0.61
- Mexico City, Mexico (metro) $0.24
- Panama City, Panama (bus) $0.25
- Quito, Ecuador (bus) $0.25 – $0.35
- Hong Kong, China (tram, ferry) $0.26 – $0.39
- Buenos Aires, Argentina (bus, subway) $0.28 – $0.32
- Beijing, China (subway) $0.30
- Dakar, Senegal (bus) $0.31
- Lima, Peru (bus) $0.36 – $0.64
- Auckland, New Zealand (bus, train) $0.38 – $1.38
- Macau, China (bus) $0.41 – $0.83
- Shanghai, China (metro) $0.45 – $1.35
- Cancun, Mexico (bus) $0.49
- Taipei, Taiwan (metro, bus) $0.49 – $2.14
- Bangkok, Thailand (skytrain, subway) $0.50 – $1.34
- Singapore, Singapore (subway, light rail) $0.61 – $1.53
- St. Petersburg, Russia (tram, bus, metro) $0.61 – $0.71
- Cartagena, Colombia (bus) $0.64 – $0.80
- Dubai, UAE (metro) $0.68 – $2.18
- Montevideo, Uruguay (bus) $0.76
- Sofia, Bulgaria (tram, bus, metro) $0.80
- Phuket, Thailand (bus) $0.83, $1.17
- Moscow, Russia (metro) $0.84
- Krakow, Poland (bus, tram) $0.86
- Seoul, South Korea (subway, bus) $0.89 – $1.77
- Prague, Czech Republic (tram, bus, metro) $1.00 – $1.44
- Santiago, Chile (metro, bus) $1.00 – $1.20
- Istanbul, Turkey (tram, bus, metro, ferry) $1.03
- Cape Town, South Africa (bus) $1.14
- Lisbon, Portugal (tram, bus, metro) $1.16 – $3.97
- New Orleans, USA (tram, bus) $1.25 – $1.50
- Rio de Janeiro, Brazil (metro, bus) $1.28 – $1.74
- Budapest, Hungary (tram, bus, metro) $1.28 – $2.32
- Athens, Greece (tram, bus, metro) $1.37
- Madrid, Spain (metro, bus) $1.37
- Monaco, Monaco (bus) $1.37
- Rome, Italy (tram, bus, metro) $1.37
- Tallinn, Estonia (bus, tram, trolley) $1.39 – $1.74
- Dubrovnik, Croatia (bus) $1.48 – $1.85
- Los Angeles, USA (bus, metro) $1.50
- Chicago, USA (metro, bus) $1.54 - $1.73
- Dublin, Ireland (tram, bus) $1.58 – $2.47
- Nice, France (bus) $1.58
- Tel Aviv, Israel (bus) $1.58
- Washington DC, USA (metro) $1.60 – $5.00
- Bruges, Belgium (bus) $1.64 - $2.74

I'll stop there, as they just get more expensive after that.

So according to this, Mexico City prices have gone up to US$0.24 now, so your best has now lost out to a few other cities, and now Caracas would probably take the prize.

Comment: I think it is Pyongyang, North Korea ;)

Comment: Boy do those prices make me proud of Sydney sitting on $2.10-$8.20.  OTOH you can travel up to 522.32km one way on that $8.20 fare, so there is that.

Comment: That price for Shanghai is for the subway--3 Yuan for the shorter runs.  Most bus fares are 2 Yuan.

Comment: If we include busses, there are [more than 30 city-wide networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_public_transport) which are entirely free. I think you could remove cities without a metro from the list.

Comment: They forgot the Tashkent Metro in Uzbekistan. $0.18

Comment: @dlanod As long as you don't count the "Airport Access Fee" when going to the airport.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException the difference, iirc, is that foreigners aren't allowed to simply ride wherever they want to on the Pyongyang Metro - you have to have a tour minder and they will tell you where you can go. For most other systems, as long as you are legally in the city you can ride trains and buses wherever you want.

Comment: Doesn't seem complete: Shenzhen is 2 RMB (US $0.28) per ride

Comment: @Hilmar you can  suggest an edit

Answer (score 22):

I'd like to add a second answer, because it's one that is cheaper but not generally accessible to do individually as a traveller.

"The [Pyongyang Metro, in North Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyongyang_Metro#Operation) was designed to operate every few minutes. During the rush hours, the trains can operate at a minimum interval of 2 minutes.

It is also one of the cheapest in the world to ride, **at only 5 KP₩ (about $0.03 USD)** per ticket."

Answer (score 19):

Some Metros aren't on PriceOfTravel.com list. Others are out of date. The list has been updated since [Mark Mayo's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5105/20576) but still outdated again quickly:

- $0.00 Caracas ([officially it's $0.10](https://www.metrodecaracas.com.ve/index.php/pagina-de-inicio/red-metro/boleteria-y-horario/) but they [stopped charging because they don't have material for tickets](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-venezuela-transportation/lacking-tickets-venezuelas-caracas-metro-gives-free-rides-idUSKCN1IW2FC))
- $0.001 Pyongyang (given current exchange rate assuming the fare is still 5 KPW)
- $0.16 Dnipropetrovsk (4 UAH)
- $0.20 Kharkov (5 UAH)
- $0.24 Yerevan
- $0.29 Tbilisi
- $0.32 Kyiv (8 UAH)
- $0.35 Minsk
- $0.35 Buenos Aires (the Premetro is only $0.03)

Comment: The Kiev is also 3 UAH on current website, although my (probably wrong) recollection is Summer 2014 the fare was only 2 on metro, 1.50 on bus.

Answer (score 8):

Also you can enjoy cheap transportation in Iran, Like:

- $0.14 Tehran, Iran (Capital City)
- $0.17 Shiraz, Iran
- $0.08 Mashhad, Iran

Prices in March 2015.

Answer (score 6):

You can take the London Underground for [free](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/getting-around-heathrow/travel-between-terminals#T5-start-content) between terminal 5 and terminals 2/3 at Heathrow. You will need an oyster card or contactless payment card though.

Answer (score 6):

Using metro in Caracas (Venezuela) is for **free** now.

With sky-rocketing inflation, printing the tickets costed more than the ride so they made it free.

Comment: A link to the site of the metro company in Caracas to back that up?

Answer (score 3):

As of Jan 2018 exchange rate of USD-INR, [Delhi Metro](http://www.delhimetrorail.com) has lowest fare of just 10 rupees or 16 US cents which I think is the lowest or second lowest in the world.
[image]

Comment: There's more than 2 examples just in the answers to this question that cost less, so it cannot be "lowest or second lowest".

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: All the examples above are 3 to 6 years old. A lot has changed in these 3 to 6 years.

Comment: So prove it. "I think" is not a valid justification for anything.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: I think is a valid justification in the case where the person has done sufficient research on the topic, is only short of having conclusive data and also has some fair idea about the topic. Besides this link should give you some idea about fares in metros around the world. Check the column "Fare": http://mic-ro.com/metro/table.html?feat=CIOPLGSTSSLILSLLSLDPTPPL&orderby=TP&sort=DESC&unit=&status=

Comment: Whatever that page is, is woefully incomplete. It doesn't even *list* prices for a good chunk of the other suggested locations in the other answers. Regardless, since you've not indicated in your answer any of this "sufficient research", your justification remains "I think".

Comment: Also that page says, right at the top: "Ticket prices by UBS (Prices and Earnings, 2009, PDF, p. 20)." So they're even older than the other answers.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: "Whatever that page is, is woefully incomplete". When rating agencies like Credit Suisse, Mercer etc. come up with various types of rankings like world's most expensive cities, world's most liveable cities etc, are their lists gleefully complete or they left behind any city? Do they take into account each and every city on the planet? And what counts as city first of all? Various countries define city differently. Your pointless argument is not helpful to anyone. You better provide an answer (which will be constructive) instead of looking for faults in my answer.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: And yes that list is the most extensive list I found on the internet as it contains almost all the metro systems in the world. Yes prices mentioned are from 2009 but it does give you a fair idea that if the Delhi Metro had the lowest fare then, then it hasn't changed much in these 7-8 years for Delhi Metro only. Exchange rates of all the currencies of the world have changed accordingly as well may be exception of yuan which may have grown stronger against the dollar which will only make Chinese metro systems expensive. But more or less prices have increased accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A ride on the Tashkent Metro in Uzbekistan costs $0.18, so it's definitely one of the cheapest