# What's the cheapest flight in the world per kilometer traveled?

Tags: air-travel, factoids

We [already have a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78113/what-is-the-cheapest-regular-priced-scheduled-flight-i-can-book-and-fly?rq=1) about the cheapest flight overall, however that only covers the total amount paid for the whole journey. I am instead interested to know which route is the cheapest in the world per kilometer traveled on board. To clarify the conditions of this questions:

- The flight must be scheduled, rather than a one time event
- The journey must take place between airports that have an IATA code
- The flight must be bookable on Google Flights or Kayak for the price you quote in your answer
- The price you quote must be stable over at least a couple of months, meaning one could reasonably book such a trip without waiting for special promotions
- If round trip tickets are cheaper, you can divide the price by two to get the per-leg cost
- Here "distance" refers to the Great Circle route between the two airports, not the actual route of the aircraft
- If the flight has more than one leg, you can only use the distance between the starting airport and the destination airport, regardless of any intermediate layovers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem. "Non-stop" flights are often priced higher than connections (even if they include the same non-stop leg) simply because they can. Sticking with mainline carriers, you have to find a route that's long and has enough non-stop competition to keep prices low.

**Mainline**: Bejing/SYD r/t in Oct. $425 on Kayak with Air China, 8942 km times 2 or for 2.37 US cent/km. That's a good route since Qantas ($455) and China Eastern do this as well. Xiamen and Sichuan offer the same route for under $350 but there are stop-overs.

**Cheap carriers**: Ryan Air offers a one way from Dublin to Bremen for $15.34 (late June). It's a 1001 km so that comes out to be 1.5c/km. Other options are Vienna and Lodz which are also in the 1.3c-1.5c/km range.

EDIT: The Ryan Air flight from DUB to Bremen shows actually up in Google flights (June 26) for $16, so I think that counts

Comment: I've updated the question to exclude the direct flight requirement as it made no sense. Hope that's okay :)

Answer (score 9):

Well, I'll kick this off by suggesting the same answer as I did in the other question: the subsidized domestic fare for flying [from Ashgabat to Balkanabad in Turkmenistan](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?DU=km&P=ASB-BKN) is 38 Turkmen manat for 385 km, which comes to **USD 0.0052/km** at the [February 2018 black market rate of 14 TMT to the dollar](https://en.hronikatm.com/2018/02/the-dollar-exchange-rate-at-the-black-market-is-four-times-as-much-as-the-official-rate/).

No, you can't book that on Google Flights, but IMHO this condition is unnecessarily restrictive since it'll also exclude <s>the vast majority of</s> some low-cost carriers (edit: Huh, looks like their coverage has improved a lot since I last checked!).

Comment: Not sure if this is the place to ask, but do you know if there are any non-google flights listed low-cost carriers in the EU?

Comment: At the official exchange rate $10 for the flight so it's 2.9c/km. @JonathanReeze: you may want to add to the rules if "black market rates" count